# Android plays sounds after delay

Tags: android, audio

I have to play sounds on GUI events, like clicking buttons etc. For this purpose, I call the following native code from WebView:

```
MediaPlayer _SoundPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
private void playSound(String sound)
{
    _SoundPlayer.reset();
    try
    {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("sound/" + sound + ".mp3");
        _SoundPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        _SoundPlayer.prepare();
        _SoundPlayer.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

The problem is there is a delay ~500ms between an event and its sound. Can I optimize playing sound somehow, maybe, creating a dedicated MediaPlayer instances for every kind of sound?

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for low-latency media playback, instead of `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Yes, though you may still see over 100ms of startup delay if the audio hardware has been disused long enough to shut down (the infamous audio flinger write delayed message)

Answer (score 4):

I see that this already has an accepted answer, but I would add that there is no complete solution at this time: Android currently has very large audio latency.  Devs are still waiting for a good solution.

This issue refers to the NDK, but the issue is general:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434

Comment: Frankly speaking, SoundPool performance doesn't look satisfactory as well. But it's a bit better and the answer is accepted as the general direction of how should a developer handle multiple sounds in their app.